# Get 1,5U voltage on the transformer

Tags: capacitor, ac, transformer, converter

I have a transformer with a midpoint that gives a voltage of 1U at the ends of its secondary winding. Can I, using only capacitors and diodes get a DC voltage of about 1.5U (but less than 2U)? If so, then how?

[image: transformer]

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

The peak voltage from a voltage source \$U\$ is given by \$ \sqrt 2 U \$ = 1.414U (which is close to your 1.5U requirement). To keep the voltage up full-wave rectification and a large capacitor value will be required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a chance of making a **voltage doubler** circuit work. There are several possible voltage doubler circuits that use only diodes and capacitors, and the one you want might be determined by the amount of current you need and how much ripple you can tolerate. At such a low voltage it might be necessary to use Schottky diodes rather than regular silicon diodes so you don't lose half of your voltage across the diode.

Answer (score 0):

Transistor is entierly right, if we interpret your question literally.

Now, I'll assume your question is a bit loosely formulated and you actually meant "Get a DC voltage that would approximately be the same as the result of a full-wave rectification from a transormer with 1.5U voltage output." So, in essence, you want to get about 1.5U * 1.414.

I'm assuming this because otherwise, the question seems suspiciously simple, and because the resulting circuit is interesting:

[image]

Basically, it is a mix between a regular rectifier and some kind of Cockcroft-Walton voltage multipler. The ground is taken between D2 and D4, like you would for a regular rectification. Then, we use the transformer center tap to feed two capacitors (C2 and C3) through two diodes (D5 and D6). The center tap is at about 0.5U voltage. When a transformer rail (e.g. the top one) goes to 0V, the capacitor (C2) charges to 0.5U through D5, then the xfmr rail goes to 1U voltage (so that gives a 1.5U voltage at the other end of the cap). This 1.5U voltage goes to the output through D1. Same for the other rail, but out-of-phase, so you get full wave rectification.

Pick whatever diodes you'd typically choose for a diode bridge (check the ratings), and dimension the three capacitors with the value you would put for a regular AC rectifer smoothing cap (considering the current you'll need and the ripple you can accept).

Here is the result with a 24V transformer and a 1kOhm load. Total input voltage is green, output is blue:

[image]